# Highcharts error #15 using Google Sheets with sorted data

Tags: sorting, highcharts

I have data in Google Sheets in the following format:

```
Column A            Column B  Column C
10/16/2017 12:50:20 77        58
10/16/2017 13:50:21 81        64
10/16/2017 14:50:17 86        64
```

My HighCharts code is very straightforward:

```
Highcharts.chart('container',{
chart: {
  type: 'line'
},
title: {
  text: 'test'
},
data: {
  googleSpreadsheetKey: ' link to my google data',
  startColumn: 0,
  endColumn: 2,

},});
```

However, when running the code I get a graph with dates starting from 1970 up to current date with Highcharts error #15, i.e. the data is allegedly not sorted.

Comment: Did you parse your `Column A` into milliseconds? If you did not, then that is your problem. **See [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data.x).**

Comment: I was able to use your data without any problems and without a need for parsing dates into milliseconds manually: http://jsfiddle.net/mec2b4ud/.

Comment: ewolden: using milliseconds didn't help, I did the change from sheets epoch to unix/Highcharts epoch. @d_paul: This is really strange, I actually cut my excel and code to barebones copy of what you had in fiddle and it still didn't work. I'm starting to think whether it might be something to do with formatting of date cells. What are you using as formatting for your data cells in Google Sheets? I cannot access the format due to view only access.

Comment: @d_paul: I copied the contents of your sample Sheets file directly to my Sheets and then copy pasted the link of my Sheets file to your fiddle and it stops working (i.e. the Highcharts starts showing x-axis of 1970-2017).  Something is different between your and my Sheets even though I have copied the contents of A1:C4 as they are

Comment: I copied the used data to a new sheet in its entirety and created a new highcharts from that and it started working. I now have two sets of the same data on different sheets with the data in a new sheet working correctly but the original data in the original sheet not working at all. The formatting of the data is same on both sheets. I'm not sure if I've managed to break the original Google sheet in some manner, but at least I'm able to present the data now. Quite strange indeed.